# Using foldl on 2dimentional lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, fold

I am trying to implement a function that collects all the values in an OrdTree in bfs order, and I also am having a hard time with this. Here is what I came with so far:

```
data OrdTree a = OrdTree a [OrdTree a]  deriving (Show)

bfsTree ::  OrdTree a ->  [a]
bfsTree tree = 
    let 
        use2DList level list (OrdTree a []) = (list!!level)++[a]
        use2DList currentLevel list (OrdTree a (branches)) =
            foldl 
                (\tree theList -> use2DList (currentLevel+1) theList tree) 
                ((list!!currentLevel)++[a]) 
                branches 
    in 
        concat (use2DList 0 [] tree)
```

and obviously I am stuck with bunch of errors I haven't managed to figure out.

1. I thought that since it's seemingly in scope, I should be able to use the `currentLevel` variable in foldl (specifically in the anonymous function), so am I? Is that okay? Or does it only have to work with the operands specified on the left of `->` ?
2. I know that stuff is immutable, but list of lists.. if I append a value to one of the lists in a list it changes it, right? But what does such code return: `(list!!position)++[value]`?
3. Would this be better if I tried to curry it like this (if I got that right):
   `foldl (use2DList (currentLevel+1)) (list!!currentLevel)++[a]) branches` or is that even worse?

Sorry if it's too much text, I am just really confused with this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean by bfs order?

```
val (OrdTree a _) = a
children (OrdTree _ ts) = ts

bfs :: [OrdTree a] -> [a]
bfs ts = (map val ts) ++ bfs (concatMap children ts)
```

Note that I've written `bfs` to take a list of `Ordtree a` not just a single tree.

- The argument to `bfs` is the list of trees at the current level.
- `map val ts` are the values at the current level
- `concatMap children ts` are all of the trees at the next level

Update: Here is some of the analysis I did on your code.

First of all it doesn't compile, so I started to remove code until I the compiler stopped complaining, and I arrived at:

```
data OrdTree a = OrdTree a [OrdTree a]  deriving (Show)

bfsTree tree =
      let
          use2DList level list (OrdTree a []) = [a] ++ (list!!level)
      in concat (use2DList 0 [] tree)
```

Note there is no type signature on `bfsTree` - we are going to have ghc tell us what the signature is, and it responds with:

```
bfsTree :: OrdTree [a] -> [a]
```

This is clearly not right - we want `OrdTree a -> [a]`. The culprit, it turns out, is the `concat`, so apparently the code should read:

```
bfsTree tree =
      let
          use2DList level list (OrdTree a []) = [a] ++ (list!!level)
      in use2DList 0 [] tree
```

Now we can ask what the type signature of `use2DList` is, and ghc (really ghc-mod) responds with:

```
use2DList :: Int -> [[a]] -> OrdTree a -> [a]
```

Now we have to figure out what the `foldl` should be. `foldl` has the signature:

```
foldl :: (s -> t -> s) -> s -> [t] -> s
```

Clearly we are folding over the branches, i.e. `t ~ OrdTree a`, and the return type of `use2DList` is `[a]`, so `s ~ [a]`, so the first argument of `foldl` should look like:

```
(\listofa tree -> ...)
```

Since your function begins `(\tree theList -> ...)` it looks like you have to parameters swapped. And that's as far as I got.

The main suggestions are:

- use GHC and the type system to help you catch errors; add type signatures to all of your definitions - including helper functions
- learn to use the `:t` command in ghci to interrogate the inferred types of functions
- use the `ghcmod-vim` plugin for vim or the haskell-mode plugin for emacs so you can interrogate sub-expressions in your program

Comment: Wow, cool, it is the solution, thanks. But is there any way to make it work the way I tried? Could you maybe point out the lamest moments so I would possibly not do them again?

Comment: I looked at your code, but there are so many type errors, that I decided to just post this. Also, the fact that you don't have the functions `val` and `children` (or the equivalent pattern matching) is a big red flag that something is very wrong. Perhaps you can explain how your algorithm is suppose to work.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize it was that bad. I thought of adding values to the 2dimentional list so that each level of values would be in a sertain position in that list, meaning something like [[topValue],[kidsOfFirstLayer],[kidsOfSecond],[etc]], and to do that I was passing the `currentValue` to indicate to which list local element should've been attached. And I do realize that apparently I am still very bad at algorithms.